# ant copy failing on makedir, getting "java.net.MalformedURLException: Invalid svn url: ${createTagDIR}"

Tags: svn, unix, ant, build

I am trying to modify a working script based on ant on solaris.
It used to ran checkout from svn url using ant copy,ant makedir and svn-checkout.

But since at a time, I was able to ran check-out for only one branch, 
I modified the script by providing properties dynamically,
Like, ant copy  `-DProperty=build_$2.properties` where $2 is branch name.
Unlike earlier we used build.properties file only almost hard coded.

After these few modifications in the shell script, I did update the build.xml being called ,with .

Now on testing parallel checkouts for different branches,or even one branch, the new script is failing with the below error.

```
***[taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties. It could not be found.
makedir:
[echo] Creating new Dir in tags directory with name ... ${TAG}
BUILD FAILED
/opt/app/d1wap1a1/devSrcRepository/scripts/SVN_DSSHTML/build.xml:130: java.net.MalformedURLException: Invalid svn url: ${createTagDIR}***
```

Please note, everything was good earlier, I guess its not an ant library issue as the error might indicate to, since without applying modifications, the script works perfect.

On feeding the right branch and release value, the script does this,

```
cat dirname_$2 |grep -v "#" | grep -i $1 >> temp_dsshtml 
numdir=cat temp_dsshtml |wc -l 
sed -e 's%BRCH%'${branch}'%g' build_tag_number.conf > build.properties 
ant copy -DProperty=build_$2.properties
```

Now as ant copy is called which as per build.xml depends on makedir target which as below-

```
   <target name="makedir" description="To create a new Directory in SVN Repository at specified URL ">  
<echo message="Creating new Dir in tags directory with name ... ${TAG}"/> 
<svn username="${SVN_USER}" password="${SVN_PWD}">  
<mkdir url="${createTagDIR}" message="Created new tag with name ${TAG}"/> 
</svn>  <echo message="Created a new DIR in the URL ... ${createTagDIR}"/> 
 </target>
```

The **createTagDIR** value is taken from **build_tag_number.conf**,which has following relevant sections u might need.

```
URL=svn://scm.it.att.com:13388/branch_name  
BURL=${URL}/branches 
TURL=${URL}/tags  
svnProject=${TURL}/${TAG}/DIRC  
BRANCH=BRCH 
DIR_CHECKOUT=DIRC  
createTagDIR=${TURL}/${TAG}
```

Now, the TAG value is picked from the line which has been uncommented for the release before the script is ran.See below.

**TAG=tb1309xxxx #TAG=tb1311xxx**

I guess, it has all details, now my observation is Since the **makedir** target could not create a new tag dir in svn location. It must be failing to get the value of **createTagDIR=${TURL}/${TAG}**, where **TURL=${URL}/tags**, and URL is defined as **URL=svn://scm.it.att.com:13388/dss** in build_tag_number.conf.

Comment: It would be helpful to post the properties file and build file. as well as relevent sections of running ant with verbose argument.  I suspect your properties file isn't being loaded - causing the path to ant-contrib jars to not exist as well as the createTagDir.

Comment: @thekbb Hi, please look into this now.